# Enable Docker CD for Linux Azure App Service in Terraform

Tags: docker, terraform, azure-web-app-service

We have a Linux App Service we're deploying with terraform and we want it to pull a new docker container every time one is pushed to our registry.

We're building this using this terraform resource:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "name"
```

To enable continuous deployment we need to enable it in the Deployment Centre or with this command:

```
az webapp deployment container config --enable-cd true --name name --resource-group rg
```

We're using terraform, so we don't want to need to supplement with CLI commands.

Is there any way to do this in terraform? I can't see anything relevant [in the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app).

Comment: Rule of thumb, if it is not in the terraform documentation you will need to use the CLI, you can wrap it in terraform null_resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource

Comment: If you feel that this is a missing feature in the `azurerm_linux_web_app` resource, report it: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi we were encountering the same problem and fixed by adding the following app setting in azurerm_linux_web_app:

```
  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_ENABLE_CI = "true"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the options suggested by Helder Sepulveda and GBI

To enable ***continous deployment*** with your Container registry, Use [azurerm_app_service_source_control](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_source_control)
 and **`container_configuration`** block:-

**`Terraform code:-`**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "silicon-rg65"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "siliconWebapp921"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {
  name                = "valleylinuxapp761"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {}
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "example" {

    container_configuration {
    image_name       = "your_image_name"
    registry_url     = "your_registry_url"
    registry_username = "your_registry_username"
    registry_password = "your_registry_password"
  }
}
```